# PHP - Rename and upload a file if it exists

Tags: php

I have recently been learning to build an image gallery uploader in PHP. I can't seem to work out how i actually rename my file before uploading it to my uploads folder. Can anyone help me please?

Heres what i have so far.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","GIF","JPEG","JPG","PNG");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Invalid File Type";
  } else {

    $target = "../upload/";
    $name = addslashes($_FILES['file']["name"]);

    if(file_exists('../upload/' . $name)) {
        $explode = explode('.', $name); 
        $img = $explode[0];
        $ex = $explode[1];
        $i = 1;
        $new = $img . '_' . $i . '.' . $ex;

        while (file_exists('../upload/' . $new)) {
          $i++;
          $new = $img . '_' . $i . '.' . $ex;
        }

        // RENAME FILE HERE? 

    } 
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}

} else {
  echo "Error uploading image";
  die();
}

}
```

So right after my while loop is where i want to rename the file then use the move_uploaded_file()function to move it into my "upload" directory. Whats the best way i can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call move_file_upload you can simply give the new file its name as the second parameter, I understand the documentation doesn't make this clear but it works.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

So you would do something like

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "Some random string to be added to the filename");
```

Or if you want to disregard the previous filename all together just remove it from your second parameter.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. "new file name here");
```

Comment: Ahh it makes sense now! I will mark this down as an answer. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: No problem, as mentioned the documentation isn't very clear on the renaming of a file but that's how its achieved

Answer (score 1):

Why not do that at the same time?

You can rename it while moving it. Simply provide new file name as second parameter of `move_uploaded_file()`.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target . $new);
```